# How to restore system from rsync backup

Tags: backup, rsync

So I recently botched part of my Ubuntu build with shred. I have been running backups via `rsync` with the command:

```
rsync -aAXv
```

And excluding `sys, proc, mnt, media, lost+found`. Media contained only personal files which are on another drive so they're safe. I tried to reinstall the OS using a live CD but the install isn't detected.

Would it make sense to try a fresh install and just copy everything I have over to the new install and fill in the gaps? How should I proceed?